# path to chromedrive on a Macbook?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to set up selenium but I am stuck with error "invalid character in identifier"

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = ‎'Macintosh HD/Users/username/Downloads/chromedriver', chrome_options=option)
```

Where is the invalid character? I have tried multiple variants and still get the same error

Comment: Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58687008/path-to-chromedrive-on-a-macbook/58687478#58687478) has solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Macintosh HD`:

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=‎'/Users/username/Downloads/chromedriver', chrome_options=option)
```

Answer (score 0):

While you want to get a path of chromedriver on Mac OS, drag and drop that file to  Terminal. So, it will give you a path of that file. 
In this case "Macintosh HD" is not required. 
You can use "/Users/username/Downloads/chromedriver" directly.